# NaN produced in logistic model

Tags: r

I am running a function calculating logistic likelihood. It works fine in Matlab, but in R it generates `NaN` values due to `0*-Inf` returning `NaN` in the internal calculation.

The codes are

```
g <- 10

ff <- 4
y <- 1

probs = 1/(1 + exp(-g*ff)) 
llh   = sum(y*log(probs) + (1-y)*log(1-probs))
```

when a value in `exp(-g*ff)` is too small, `probs` will be very close to 1, and `log(1-probs)` will close to -Inf, and `NaN` will produced.

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?  Using `plogis(x, log.p=TRUE)` and `plogis(x, lower.tail=FALSE, log.p=TRUE)` to get the log(p) and log(1-p) directly will probably solve most of your problems...

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your answer. I just edited the question, let's assume ff=4, y=1, then llh will yield NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plogis()` is the built-in function in R for the logistic function (it's the CDF  of the logistic *distribution*). Using `plogis(g*ff, log.p=TRUE)` to get the log-probability and `plogis(g*ff, log.p=TRUE, lower.tail=FALSE)` to get the complementary log-probability should work:

```
llh <- sum(y*plogis(g*ff,log.p=TRUE) +
           (1-y)*plogis(g*ff, log.p=TRUE, lower.tail=FALSE))
```

For less extreme values (e.g. `g <- 1`) this seems to agree with your approach.

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates "thank you" comments; if this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept the answer.